# CSS Checked + Label Styling Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a label associated with a radio button that needs to have styling updated upon being checked. For some reason the below code is not working.
Appreciate your feedback.

CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    border: 2px solid $primary;
    &:before {
      content: "\f00c";
      display: block;
      background: $primary;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="grid__item one-third small--one-half">
    <input type="radio" name="Hamper option" class="hide hamper-option" value="3782230835231" id="3782230835231" data-name="Robert Mondavi Napa Valley Pinot Noir Carneros 2012" data-price="19900" data-image="image-robert-mondavi-napa-valley-pinot-noir-carneros-2012" checked="checked">
    <label class="product-select" for="3782230835231">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/249df4/0ff534/products/71dfTfTyxzEqL._SY500_small.jpg?v=1510096df324" alt="Default Title">
        </div>
        <div class="product-info">
            <small>A Wine Bottle</small>
            Robert Mondavi Napa Valley Pinot Noir Carneros 2012<br>
            $199.00
        </div> 
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean `type="radio"` ? https://jsfiddle.net/7k23tyLq/

Comment: legend. It's working. How could I have been so stupid.